# XA transaction - javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to acquire the pool semaphore, strictTimeout=-1

Tags: jms, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, xa, tibco-ems

I'm playing with XA transactions. At the moment, I'm trying to integrate them with JMS. But instead I get some cryptic exceptions about failed semaphore acquisition.

Here is my **MDB**:

```
@javax.ejb.MessageDriven(messageListenerInterface = MessageListener.class)
@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.AspectDomain("Tibco/Simple.Request.Queue")
@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool(
    value = PoolDefaults.POOL_IMPLEMENTATION_STRICTMAX, 
    maxSize = 1, 
    timeout = Long.MAX_VALUE
)
public class FeedReconciliationMessageBean implements MessageListener {

    @EJB
    private SimpleController simpleController;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(TrsFeedReconciliationRequestPayload message) {
        simpleController.reconciliate(message.getReconId());
    }

}
```

**Activation config**:

```
    <domain name="Tibco/Simple.Request.Queue" extends="Message Driven Bean" inheritBindings="true">
    <annotation expr="!class(@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.DefaultActivationSpecs)">
    @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.DefaultActivationSpecs 
        (value={ 
        @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", 
            propertyValue="/com/example/Simple.Request.Queue:queue"),
        @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="user",
                                            propertyValue=""), 
        @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="password",
                                            propertyValue=""), 
        @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="providerAdapterJNDI", 
                                            propertyValue="java:/TIBCOJMSProvider"), 
        @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", 
                                            propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),
        @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="useDLQ",
                                            propertyValue="false"),
        @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="transactionTimeout",
                                            propertyValue="43200000") })
    </annotation>
</domain>
```

**Queue configuration**:

```
show queue Simple.Request.Queue
 Queue:                 Simple.Request.Queue
 Type:                  static
 Properties:            *prefetch=5,*store=$sys.nonfailsafe
 JNDI Names:            "/com/example/Simple.Request.Queue:queue"
 Bridges:               <none>
 Receivers:             1
 Pending Msgs:          0
 Delivered Msgs:        0
 Pending Msgs Size:     0.0 Kb
```

So, every time I send a message to the queue, I get an exception like this:

```
2014-04-03 09:44:10,734 [WorkManager(2)-64] ERROR [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsServerSession] Unexpected error delivering message MapMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={ID:EMS-SERVER.3585339006611AE:4} JMSDestination={Queue[Simple.Request.Queue]} JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={PERSISTENT} JMSRedelivered={true} JMSCorrelationID={null} JMSType={null} JMSTimestamp={Thu Apr 03 09:44:10 MSD 2014} JMSExpiration={0} JMSPriority={4} } Properties={ JMSXDeliveryCount={Integer:7} } Fields={ userSessionId={null} payloadType={String:SimplePayload} processInstanceId={null} payloadFullType={String:com.example.SimplePayload} payload={String:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SimplePayload>
    <test>1</test>
</SimplePayload>
} } }

javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to acquire the pool semaphore, strictTimeout=-1
    at org.jboss.ejb3.pool.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:127)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
```

Interesting thing is that the MDB does get called. I have a breakpoint set in `onMessage` method, and when the message is sent, I do stop in the `onMessage` method. But at the same time, I get about 7 exceptions like the one above in my server.log.

Another interesting thing is that `onMessage` is called twice, even though, no exception during its execution occurs.

I tried to google this problem. The most common solution that I'd found was *increase the ejb pool size*. The explanation was that if you have JMS **prefetch size** less than EJB **pool size** it might occur that there are not enough EJBs in the pool to process all the messages. So, after a timeout the exception is thrown. But as you can see, this is something completely different. Why the **strictTimeout** value in the exception is -1? I think it has something to do with XA transactions.

Comment: This might be caused by the following setting: timeout = Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @steve No, the first time I encountered this problem, there wasn't such a setting. I added it later, hoping that this would help, but to no avail.